# How do you change the font family and font size for ui-kitten Tab component

Tags: react-native-ui-kitten

I am struggling to understand how I can change the font-family, font-size, bold, etc for the Tab component.

Can someone point me in the right direction

Many thanks

Stephen (SquareHat)

p.s. I could not find the tag ui-kitten as suggested on the web-page

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the text on the Tab component, you should pass a own Text component to the title property like this

```
<Tab title={evaProps => <Text {...evaProps} style={{color: 'blue'}}>USERS</Text>}>
```

On that text, you can use the style that you want!